# Flutter: Why LinkedHashMap..addAll replaced all old data instead of append

Tags: flutter, firebase, linkedhashmap, table-calendar

sample list:

```
_events = [{ "name" : "A", "date" : "15 jun" },
{ "name" : "B", "date" : "15 jun" },
{ "name" : "C", "date" : "17 jun" },
{ "name" : "D", "date" : "17 jun" },]


kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<dynamic>>(equals: isSameDay, hashCode: getHashCode)
      ..addAll(_events);

int getHashCode(DateTime key) {
  return key.day * 1000000 + key.month * 10000 + key.year;
}
```

i am expecting the kEvents will be displaying all data for a particular day, for example if kEvents['27 jun'] it should become:

```
[{ "name" : "C", "date" : "17 jun" },
    { "name" : "D", "date" : "17 jun" },]
```

however my result was:

```
[{ "name" : "D", "date" : "17 jun" }]
```

the last item replaced previous item instead of append to the list.... why?

Answer (score 0):

`kEvents` is a `LinkedHashMap`.  `_events` is a *`List`* of `LinkedHashMap`s.  A single `LinkedHashMap` can store only one element for  each key; hence there is only one value for `'name'` and one value for `'key'`.

If you want to reorganize `_events` by date, then you'd need to iterate over `_events` and generate a new `Map` with dates as the keys and `List`s as the values.  For example:

```dart
var _events = [
  {"name": "A", "date": "15 jun"},
  {"name": "B", "date": "15 jun"},
  {"name": "C", "date": "17 jun"},
  {"name": "D", "date": "17 jun"},
];

void main() {
  var byDate = <String, List<String>>{};
  for (var map in _events) {
    (byDate[map['date']!] ??= []).add(map['name']!);
  }

  print(byDate); // Prints: {15 jun: [A, B], 17 jun: [C, D]}
}
```